# How can I restrict Paperclip to only accept images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

How can I restrict [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) to only accept images? I'm using Amazon S3 for storage if that's relevant. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Moonpatrol's got a wicked answer for this. I'd accept his answer for newcomers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Paperclip has validation methods like `validates_attachment_presence`, `validates_attachment_content_type`, and `validates_attachment_size`.

So all you need to do is pass mime types of images you'd like to have as attachments:

```
validates_attachment_content_type 'image/png', 'image/jpg'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Regarding this from the rdoc: "It should be noted that Internet Explorer upload files with content_types that you may not expect. For example, JPEG images are given image/pjpeg and PNGs are image/x-png, so keep that in mind when determining how you match. Allows all by default. ", is there a standard list I can use that will allow all images in all browsers?

Comment: Not that i know of. You can try using wildcard like `image/*` but i'm not sure if paperclip supports that.

Comment: The content_type "can be a String or a Regexp" according to the RDoc here http://rdoc.info/gems/paperclip/2.3.8/Paperclip/ClassMethods:validates_attachment_content_type

Comment: are the parameters to validates_attachment_content_type correct?

Answer (score 25):

From https://makandracards.com/makandra/606-only-allow-pictures-as-paperclip-attachments

```
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /^image\/(jpg|jpeg|pjpeg|png|x-png|gif)$/, :message => 'file type is not allowed (only jpeg/png/gif images)'
```

Comment: For Rails 4, the regex should be `/\Aimage\/(jpg|jpeg|pjpeg|png|x-png|gif)\z/`.

Comment: How would I write it if I only wanted to restrict to .csv files? validates_attachment_content_type :csv, :content_type => /^csv\/(csv)$/, :message => 'file type is not allowed (only csv files)'