# Ruby validation - multiple permutations for a single hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, paperclip, paperclip-validation

Say there is a hash field that can have two possible value permutations, "foo" and "bar". How can I validate the hash value is one of the two?

```
class ValidateMe
  validates :type => { :type => "foo" or :type => "bar" }
end
```

**This results in an error.** What is the proper way to handle this use case?

---

My actual case is using Paperclip to attach an image. I need to enforce the image is only .png or .jpg

```
class ValidateMe
  validates_attachment :image, 
                       presence => true, 
                       :content_type => { :content_type => "image/png" }
end
```

Help with either code block is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to pass an array of types to `:content_type`

```
class ValidateMe
  validates_attachment :image, 
                       presence => true, 
                       :content_type => { :content_type => ['image/png', 'image/jpeg'] }
end
```

(My answer is based on code in  [Paperclip - Validate File Type but not Presence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807008/paperclip-validate-file-type-but-not-presence))

This can also be done using regular expressions. (Not as preferable)

```
class ValidateMe
  validates_attachment :image, 
                       presence => true, 
                       :content_type => { :content_type => /^image\/(jpeg|png)$/ }
end
```

(source [How can I restrict Paperclip to only accept images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676902/how-can-i-restrict-paperclip-to-only-accept-images/10059772#10059772))

Answer (score 1):

I think Btuman's first answer would be considered canonical: The content_type key of content_type in validates_attachment can accept an array of valid content-types.

Comment: There's always more than one way to do it. Maybe canonical isn't quite right. It's just the style I've personally always seen used, and is, I think better documented. Furthermore, I'd avoid the regular expression there, as I think it is needlessly complex.

Comment: Ah, true, I just wanted to include more then one way just in case, but I will edit the answer to make sure to add your point

Answer (score 0):

You can use :inclusion attribute for more see this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html